# passing a type to IDBConnection Get < T > ()

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to pass a type during runtime to `IDBConnection.Get<T>` extension?

For example, I have classes like Countries, States, Cities, and an object variable instance containing either of those. And I want to pass the class type to `Get<T>` method

Pseudocode :

```
var myobject = _somedata;  //it could be of type countries, states, cities, etc...

var q = sqlConn.Get<typeof(myobject)>()
```

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Comment: It is possible, but this should not be done that way. What is the purpose to do those operations in this way?

Comment: What type would `myobject` and `q` have in your example? Please replace `var` in your example with the actual types the compiler would infer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you don't want to. The resulting code is nasty.

Instead, try writing your own extension method that uses the type of an argument.

```
public static T GetLike<T>(this IDbConnection conn, T likeType)
{
    return conn.Get<T>();
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
var q = sqlConn.GetLike(myobject);
```

And the anonymous type will be inferred by the compiler.